# android Map get whole Earth first

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Iam using google map  and on Activity Ready first it`s show whole earth
and then camera move to my Location

I want to get my location direct without moving camera

```
  @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            aroundmemap = googleMap;
            Location locat = myLocationService.mycurrentlocationn;
            if (locat != null) {
                CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(locat.getLatitude(), locat.getLongitude()))
                        .zoom(15).build();
                aroundmemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));

            }}
```

Comment: use animations.

Comment: Did you try moveCamera ? It shows location with lesser movement.

Comment: yes , and it also do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the camera without animating, use `aroundmemap.moveCamera` instead of `animateCamera`. See [the Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#updating_the_camera_view) for more about moving the camera.

Comment: i will try it :(